# XHR2 одна для всех

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!) Пытаюсь сделать функцию, которая бы отправляла запрос обработчику и возвращала результат:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function Req(data,url) {
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('post',url, true);
                xhr.onload=function(e){
                    return this.response;
                }
                xhr.send(data);
            }
    </head>
    <body onLoad="alert(Req('','authentication.php'));">
    </body>
 </html>
```

Но возвращает она '`undefined`' то есть она не работает.
Вопрос почему, и как заставить её работать?
Или я что то не так делаю ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно передать аргументом функцию, вроде вот так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function Req(data,url,callback) {
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('post',url, true);
                xhr.onload=function(e){
                    callback(this.response);
                }
                xhr.send(data);
            }
         </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="Req('','authentication.php',alert);">
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Само собой функция `Req` возвращает `undefined`, в ней же нет инструкции `return`. При запросе через `XMLHttpRequest` функция `xhr.onload` выполняется асинхронно (третий параметр `xhr.open` - `true`), то есть не в момент её объявление и не в момент вызова `xhr.send`, а тогда, когда будут получены данные с сервера. А это может произойти (и скорее всего произойдёт) после завершения работы функции `Req`. Всю логику обработки полученных данных нужно помещать в функция `xhr.onload`:

```
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    alert(xhr.response);
}
```

Comment: Так что, вообще невозможно реализовать вариант где функция возвращает this.response?

Comment: А если сделать что то подобное return xhr.onload=function(e){return this.response;};

Comment: Вернуть-то она вернёт, но куда? Ведь функцию `xhr.onload` вызываете не вы, а браузер, когда приходят данные с сервера. Если вы хотите, чтобы принятые данные были доступны вне `xhr.onload`, скопируйте их в глобальную переменную.

Comment: @fori1ton плохая идея, т.к. следующий вопрос будет - "а чего это я отправил запрос, а переменная не обновилась"....

Answer (score -1):

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post',url, false);
xhr.send(data);
return xhr.response;
```

Comment: Делать запрос синхронным плохая идея. Что если данных придёт слишком много или у пользователя медленное соединение? Интерфейс просто подвиснет, ожидая ответ.

Comment: Обычно всё равно получиться асинхрон. Пользователь нажал на кнопку, данные грузятся. В это время он может нажать на другую кнопку, возникнет ещё одно событие, и js код запуститься отдельным потоком

Comment: Вы не правы. JavaScript однопоточен. Вот: http://jsfiddle.net/xwhsL/1/ Попробуйте нажать кнопук script1, а затем script2.

Comment: Но при таком раскладе нет разницы между асинхронным и синхронным соединением!

Comment: И кстати danpetruk ваш способ не работает xhr.response будет пуст.

Comment: Сорри, там так должно быть - xhr.responseText

Comment: Всё работает спасибо большое!)